# Azure Portals Dashboard, adding new virtual machine hangs at loading panel

Tags: azure

I really didn't wanted to ask that kind of question in this resource, but I have no choice.

I have tried ask this question to Azure Support on Twitter, but they told me to open support case in azure portal itself. However, if you want to use their direct support, you must pay money.

MSDN forums does not allow me to post screenshots until it verifies my account, so this makes posting there useless.

When I want to add new Virtual machine I press `Add` button on `Virtual Machines` tab. Then it opens new tab with loading message and hangs. It says loading and then nothing happens.

I have cleared cache of my browser, opended incognito mode, still this happens.

I have installed another browser, opened portal and Dashboard still hangs at loading tab.

I have tried to open portal on my friends computers, problem still persists.

This is screenshot of this problem:

[image: screenshot1]

This is Javascript console:

[image: console]

According to this screenshot, Azure Portals Dashboard has javascript errors.

Why this is happening? Did I encounter some kind of bug?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question; it appears to be some portal-specific issue. As you mentioned in your question, you should post this to MSDN forum. If you can't upload images, you can always include links to external image sites like imgur.

Comment: @DavidMakogon External links also unavailable. :(

Answer (score 0):

As David said, it is not directly related to the forum, but there was partial portal outage, according to the https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/. North America users were impacted.

Looks like that issue was mitigated.

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or as the answer. Thanks!